# declaring link attributes inside a class in css

Tags: css

Why is the second link not yellow? There is the class myclass and there is declared every link's color inside the class to be yellow. However, it is blue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>hey I am a title</title>
    <style>
a:link,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:active {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a.myclass:link,
a.myclass:hover,
a.myclass:visited,
a.myclass:active {
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="indexde.htm">first link</a>

<br><br>

<span class="myclass">
    <a href="indexde.htm">second link</a>
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using `a.myclass:hover` when you probably ment to use `.myclass a:hover` and such

Comment: its the span which has the class

Comment: @JanN. I also recommend instead of selecting `hover`, `visited`, etc. You should use `!important` on your css properties instead. It's a shorter way of making it yellow no matter what.

Comment: i wouldn't recommend that, that is a really bad habbit. That prevents the normal rules of precedence/specificity from being in effect and can cause many headaches down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
a.myclass:link,
a.myclass:hover,
a.myclass:visited,
a.myclass:active {
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

to

```
.myclass a:link,
.myclass a:hover,
.myclass a:visited,
.myclass a:active {
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```